# How can I fix sed invalid command code '?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, sed

I have a shell script with below 2 commands:

```
sedcmd1="sed -i '' '/<PromptOnUpdate>true<\/PromptOnUpdate>/G' /Users/abc/data.xml"
$sedcmd1
```

when I run the script I get below error:

```
sed: 1: "'/<PromptOnUpdate ...": invalid command code '
```

If I run the command without assigning it to the variable, it runs just fine. But I get an error only when I assign it to a variable an execute it from there.

I need the command in the variable for my needs, as I am try to receive the command as a argument to the shell script.

Snippet of data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Settings Version="1.0.0">
    <Android>
       <PromptOnUpdate>true</PromptOnUpdate>
    </Android>
</Settings>
```

Thanks for looking into this!

PS: I am on Mac OSX Mavericks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes aren't processed after expanding a variable. You need to use `eval`:

```
eval "$sedcmd1"
```

Comment: Note that the array technique in @John1024's answer is generally considered a better solution. If you have nested quotes in the command, they're harder to deal with using `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

The shell processes quotes before it expands variables.  That means that the quotes inside your variable have no magic; they are treated the same as any other character.

To store a complex command as a variable, you need an array:

```
sedcmd1=(sed -i '' '/<PromptOnUpdate>true<\/PromptOnUpdate>/G' data.xml)
```

The array can be executed:

```
${sedcmd1[@]}
```

If you are unsure if you have defined your array character, you can always see what is in it using the `declare` command;

```
declare -p sedcmd1
```

which yields:

```
declare -a sedcmd1='([0]="sed" [1]="-i" [2]="" [3]="/<PromptOnUpdate>true<\\/PromptOnUpdate>/G" [4]="data.xml")'
```